# Merging 2 dataframes in pandas results in duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df:

m2 =

```
2014-02     1
2014-09     1
2014-11     1
...
2016-11    10
2016-12     9
2017-01     9
2017-02    10
2017-04     2
Name: Start Date2, dtype: int64
```

m1 =

```
2010-09     1
2010-12     1
2011-03     1
2011-04     1
2011-05     2
...
2016-11     8
2016-12    12
2017-01     7
2017-02     5
2017-04     1
Name: Start Date, dtype: int64
```

What I want is a single df like this:
merged =

```
2010-09     1     NaN
2010-12     1     NaN
...
2017-02     5     10
2017-04     1     2
```

I tried multiple versions of this (they are series so I transform them to dataframes first):

```
result = pd.DataFrame(m1).reset_index().merge(pd.DataFrame(m2), left_on="Start Date", right_on="Start Date2", how='inner').set_index('index')
result.to_csv("out.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

But I get something like this:

```
2010-09 1   1
2010-09 1   1
...   
2016-12 12  12
2016-12 12  12
2016-09 8   8
2016-11 8   8
```

If I try with `outer` (which is what I want), I get:

```
2016-12 12.0    12.0
2016-12 12.0    12.0
2016-06 7.0 
2016-08 7.0 
2017-01 7.0 
2016-09 8.0 8.0
2016-11 8.0 8.0
        10.0
        10.0
        10.0
        10.0
        10.0
        17.0
        9.0
        9.0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you reset the index for `m2` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for `merge` is

```
pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None,
         left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
         suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False)
```

So you can just do

```
pd.merge(m1, m2, how='outer, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

if `m1` and `m2` are series, you might need to replace them in the `pd.merge`-call with `m1.to_frame()`

No need to `reset_index`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes with reset_index(), that is giving the name 'Start Date' and 'Start Date2' to the data column name, not to the index values.

Try the following:

```
m1 = pd.DataFrame(m1).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Start Date','Start Date':'values'})
m2 = pd.DataFrame(m2).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Start Date2','Start Date2':'values2'})
m1.merge(m2,left_on= 'Start Date',right_on='Start Date2',how='outer')
```

That should make it.